# Android -- First ListView item is sometimes selected when ListView is initially displayed

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

When I press Menu and the `ListView` is presented, the top item is usually highlighted when the Activity is first started. I can click and make it not highlighted. What might be causing this? Actually I don't care about that, I just need a hack to stop it.  I would post a code snippet but the `ListActivity` and its xml exceed 600 lines and I have no idea where the problem lies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be pretty easy: The first entry of every ListView is highlighted, when you are in the "non touch mode". That means when you navigate with the trackball.

Test it: Go the the home screen. Press the menu button and select "settings" with the trackball. The list displaying the settings main menu is now highlighted in the first row.

Doing the same without the trackball but with a touch on the menu entry "settings" the new list should be not highlighted.

Comment: You're right, that's the cause. What might the solution be? My program uses the trackball.

Comment: I don't recommend to change the default behavior as it isn't what the user might expect and is used to. But I can think of two things that might work: try to disable focus in the xml layout and enable focus in `onResume()`. I am not sure if this works because I don't know at which point the highlight will be processed. Btw: I hate it if I use the trackball and have no clue where the current select is...